# Errors in starting postgresql-9.5.3 on windows. Required .conf files missing

Tags: postgresql

version: 9.5.3

I have installed the above version downloading postgresql-9.5.3-1-windows-x64-binaries.zip from www.postgresql.org
Below is the output of postgres command...

---

```
D:\postgresql-9.5.3-1-windows-x64-binaries\pgsql\bin>postgres
postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.
```

---

I have no idea where to locate those configuration files. I have tried setting PGDATA but there also it expects required .conf files to be present which are not there. I found some .conf files in pgsql\share but these are not enough.

From where to get the required .conf files for starting above version?

Comment: Did you run [`initdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-initdb.html)? If yes, then which data directory did you specify? If no, then you have to do that. You should also start the server using `pg_ctl.exe` **not** `postgres.exe` (once you have initialized the data directory using `initdb`)

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime.html) which will tell you how to create, configure and start a PostgreSQL cluster.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name- great! I am able to start the server with initdb and pg_ctl. Do you have any idea how to check what credentials are created for first time so that I can use those to login with psql. I tried but fatat errors. 1. FATAL:  database "praklenovo" does not exist when no username specified and 2. FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist when --username=postgres. Do I need to run some script initially?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name- ok, I got this running successfully after createuser, createdb commands. I can connect now using psql.